# Fill NaN with group-by other column in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Data**

```
 Col1 Col2    result
0  a    x      123.0 
1  a    y     NaN    
2  a    x      453.0 
3  a    y      675.0 
4  b    z      786.0 
5  b    z      332.0
```

I want to fill NaN with 675.0, first group by col1 then by col2 and fill the NaN value

**In Pandas**

```
df['result'] = df['result'].fillna(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', ])['result'].bfill())


df['result'] = df['result'].fillna(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', ])['result'].ffill())
```

How I can implement it in pyspark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via [pandas udfs](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html). Then you can use the functions you want directly.

```
[IN]
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

s = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a","a","a","a","b","b"],
              "col2": ["x", "y", "x", "y", "z", "z"],
              "result": [123, np.nan, 453, 675, 786, 332]})

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(s)

grouped_spark_df = spark_df.groupBy("col1", "col2")

@pandas_udf("col1 string, col2 string, result float", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def fillnaspark(df):
    df['result'] = df['result'].bfill()
    df['result'] = df['result'].ffill()
    return df

grouped_spark_df.apply(fillnaspark).show()

[OUT]
+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|result|
+----+----+------+
|   a|   x| 123.0|
|   a|   x| 453.0|
|   b|   z| 786.0|
|   b|   z| 332.0|
|   a|   y| 675.0|
|   a|   y| 675.0|
+----+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nanvl` to replace `NaN` with the `lead` value of result (equivalent to `ffill`; `bfill` would be `lag`):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'id', F.monotonically_increasing_id()
).withColumn(
    'result', 
    F.nanvl(
        'result',
        F.coalesce(
            F.lag('result').over(Window.partitionBy('Col1', 'Col2').orderBy('id')),
            F.lead('result').over(Window.partitionBy('Col1', 'Col2').orderBy('id'))
        )
    )
).orderBy('id')

df2.show()
+---+----+----+------+
| id|Col1|Col2|result|
+---+----+----+------+
|  0|   a|   x| 123.0|
|  1|   a|   y| 675.0|
|  2|   a|   x| 453.0|
|  3|   a|   y| 675.0|
|  4|   b|   x| 786.0|
|  5|   b|   y| 332.0|
+---+----+----+------+
```

Comment: `
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns:`

Comment: Oh I didn't realise `id` is not a column. You can try the edited solution.

Comment: something is wrong here the number of missing values should be reduced to  374,323 from 589,784,  but with this code it increased to 3,354,901

Comment: I can't see your data, so I'm afraid I can't tell what's wrong. It would be great if you could provide some relevant sample data to explain your issue.

Comment: The real data looks same as given in the question the differences are: `result` column is string and NaN value appears sometime before or after the value (after grouping ) that is why I am applying ``.ffill()`` and ``.bfill()`` both

Comment: how did you calculate the number of missing values?

Comment: `df.filter((df["result"] == "") | df["result"].isNull() | isnan(df["result"])).count()
`

Comment: I suspect some `NaN` are replaced with `""` in the value before/after, though this should not result in a huge increase in the number of missing values.

Comment: There is no `" "`, all are strings and null. I get perfect results with the pandas

Comment: then why are you filtering with the condition `(df["result"] == "")`?

Comment: just to see if there is any `" "` ,even without `(df["result"] == "")` I still get 3,354, 901 null values